# Layered navigation (Shop by) not showing on every category

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, cms-block, design

I hope you can help me out here.. I tried every possible solution given on the forum / internet, but nothing helps. Maybe I'm overseeing something here.

I'm using the default RWD template with magento 1.9.2 (incl. sample data).
When you look at: `http://www.kweekotheek.nl/nieuw2/kweeklampen/shirts.html` you can see that it works ok.
Looking at `http://www.kweekotheek.nl/nieuw2/kweeklampen.html` you see it doesn't show up :(

The anchor option in the categories are the same ("Yes"). Cleared the cache, set it to "No" and back to "Yes", but nothing changes. It's almost a clean install (didn't work from the beginning).

Hope you guru's can help me out here :)

Thanks in advance!

Hielke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go & update the settings from admin:

**Catalog->Manage Categories-> Your category-> Custom Design-> Page Layout-> set "2 columns with left bar".**

Comment: Thank you guys! This solved my 'problem' :) You're the best Qaisar and Credevator!!

Answer (score 2):

You must select "Is Anchor = Yes" to every category you want to display layered navigation

Answer (score 0):

This is due to page design settings.
Your category where shop by options are not available is a `1column` layout where shop by options will be listed in `2columns-left`.
Update the design settings and you are done.